# Best way to define Constants in Ruby/ RoR at one place

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have multiple classes (4-5) using same constant value, say PI = 3.14. 
What is the best way to define that constant at one place in Ruby and in RoR application?

Do I construct one module with given Constant and include in all the classes that are using it?

What are best practices and standard Ruby or RoR way?

Comment: Pi is already defined as a constant in `Math::PI`. You should come up with better example. Usually all the constants are somehow related to the field your app is working in, so maybe you can put constants in the model they are related to?

Comment: Sure. But what about constants that are related to more than one model. We might end up with what @sergio has mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of including this constant everywhere, you could just define it in one place and then refer that  directly

```
# config/initializers/constants.rb, for example.
module Constants
  PI = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971
end

# app/models/circle.rb
class Circle
  attr_reader :radius

  def area
    Constants::PI * radius ** 2
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, is there any way to make it Hierarchical, for instance, I want math constants to be at one place and can be used as Constants::Math::PI

Comment: "is there any way to make it Hierarchical" of course, just define modules within module. This is basic ruby.

Comment: Sure, is there any way to easily include all constants of particular module deep in Hierarchy so that I dont need to say Constants::Math::Circle::PI everywhere but just PI and Ruby intelligently knows what I mean. It is similar to having static import in java.

Comment: You can mixin the module to a class with `include`.  In this answer, add `include Constants` right below `class Circle`, then you can shorten `Constants::PI` to just `PI`.  Watch out for a polluted namespace that no one can read, though.

Comment: Can I include just submodule, for instance, Constants:: Math and allow constants inside Math to be available and not others inside Constants modules other than Math.

Answer (score 2):

All your application classes shall be under a namespace, given `MyApp`.

So all shared constants could be declared in the `MyApp` module :

```
module MyApp
  APP_CONST_1 = 42
  APP_CONST_2 = 3.14
  # ...
end

class MyApp::User
  def the_answer
    MyApp::APP_CONST_1 # 42
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Start using concerns, RubyOnRails has this beautiful pattern to refactor code.

Check out this:

http://vaidehijoshi.github.io/blog/2015/10/13/stop-worrying-and-start-being-concerned-activesupport-concerns/